# How to handle "curl -XGET http://testdomain.com --request-target example.com:80" with Gorilla

Tags: go

How do I create a Path or PathPrefix in Gorilla http framework if the user forces a URI that does not begin with a slash? This causes a direct to whatever the user specifies, e.g.:

```
# curl -Iv http://testdomain.com --request-target example.com:80
* Added testdomain.com to DNS cache
* Hostname testdomain.com was found in DNS cache
> HEAD example:80 HTTP/1.1
> Host: testdomain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: example:80
Location: example:80
< Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2022 18:53:03 GMT
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2022 18:53:03 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host REDACTED left intact
```

Currently, it does not match anything in my route setup, yet generates a redirect. Middle-ware is also not catching anything to act on:

```
func filterMW(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    logrus.Infof("In filterMW")
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    dump, _ := httputil.DumpRequest(r, false)
    logrus.Infof("%v", string(dump))
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

httpRouter := mux.NewRouter()
httpRouter.Use(filterMW)
```

Thoughts?

Edit: Updated to include more details!

Comment: Use `/`. Gorilla Mux [translates an empty path to '/'](https://github.com/gorilla/mux/blob/98cb6bf42e086f6af920b965c38cacc07402d51b/mux.go#L463-L465).

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but would [StrictSlash](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.StrictSlash) help in this scenario?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne strict slash doesn't help. I added more to the problem description. Thanks!

Comment: @farhany from what I understood from reading up on this case, it looks like that need to be checked on the web server level (Gorilla Mux). I'm more sure you can catch that case.